# Create a team generator with a given number of teams

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I would like to take an array of `[String]` and split it up into a given number of groups.

I have tried using this extension

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to:count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

to split the array into a given number of elements per subarray, which for that function it works.
But to split it into a desired number of subarrays, I tried dividing the `array.count` by the desired number of teams, which works but only in certain circumstances.
If there are any extra elements, it puts them into an extra subarray at the end, and the number needs to come out even if I want this to work perfectly, which is the minority of the time.
So I guess this `array.chunked` function is not the solution in any way.

Maybe there is a way to do it with a for loop by taking an `array.randomElement()`, adding that to a variable (which would be a team) and then removing that element from the original array, and iterating over it until the original array is empty. And end up with an array of subarrays which would be the teams, or just separate variables which would be the teams. It could be any of those options.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: There is no picking strategy that would let you split an odd number of people into two equal sized teams. It's just not possible. The closest you can probably do is to take the "leftovers" (the last sub-array returned by `Array.chunked(into:)`), and distribute those players among the existing teams, so that team size differs by 1 at most

Comment: @Alexander Yes that's what I was thinking about. The problem is that sometimes more than 1 array would end up as extra and the Array.chunked(into:) function just sets a limit at how many elements there can be per array.

Comment: Do you want to pick team members randomly?

Comment: @DuncanC Yes but I can just pass in the array as .shuffled().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about how you deal cards.

If you have 7 players, you start with one player and go around, giving one card at a time to each player. At the end, you may run out of cards before giving everybody the same number of cards. Some people may have n cards, and some may have n-1. That's the best that you can do.

You could implement the same thing with a source array and your destination arrays. Remove one element at a time from the source array, and "round-robbin" add it to one of the destination arrays until the source array is exhausted.

That code might look like this:

```
func splitArray<T>(array: [T], subArrayCount: Int) -> [[T]] {
    
    // Create an empty array of arrays
    var result = [[T]]()
    
    // Create the empty inner string arrays
    for _ in 1...subArrayCount {
        let innerArray = [T]()
        result.append(innerArray)
    }
    for (index, element) in array.enumerated() {
        result[index % subArrayCount].append(element)
    }
    return result
}
```

And to test it:

```
let string = "Now is the time for all good programmers to babble incoherently. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. Fourscore and seven years ago our forefathers brought forth to this continent a new nation conceived in liberty and dedicated to the cause that all men are created equal."

let array = string.split(separator: " ")
    .map { String($0) }

let subArrays: [[String]] = splitArray(array: array, subArrayCount: 5)

for (index, array) in subArrays.enumerated() {
    let countString = String(format: "%2d", array.count)
    print ("Array[\(index)]. Count = \(countString). Contents = \(array)")
}
```

The output of that test is:

```
Array[0]. Count = 10. Contents = ["Now", "all", "incoherently.", "falls", "Fourscore", "our", "this", "conceived", "to", "men"]
Array[1]. Count = 10. Contents = ["is", "good", "The", "mainly", "and", "forefathers", "continent", "in", "the", "are"]
Array[2]. Count = 10. Contents = ["the", "programmers", "rain", "on", "seven", "brought", "a", "liberty", "cause", "created"]
Array[3]. Count = 10. Contents = ["time", "to", "in", "the", "years", "forth", "new", "and", "that", "equal."]
Array[4]. Count =  9. Contents = ["for", "babble", "spain", "plain.", "ago", "to", "nation", "dedicated", "all"]
```

Comment: So I should make a for loop to continuously add an element from the source array to the other arrays? How do I tell the for loop to which array it should add the element? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm getting an error in the declaration of the second for loop that says "Tuple pattern cannot match values of non-tuple type 'String'". How can I fix this?

Comment: Yup. I should know better than to type code in the SO editor. I updated my answer.

Comment: I refactored the function to use Generics, so it will split arrays of any type.